# Running Python or PowerShell in VBA Outlook

Tags: python, vba, powershell, outlook

I am trying to run a Python script using VBA in Outlook. The Python script is to fetch data using REST API and write to file in the system. I am using VBA to orchestrate this with sending emails.

The Python script (`get_people.py`) runs from OS. It calls a REST API and gets a list of peoples names and writes to a file in OS.

I tried two methods:

1. Wrapping the Python execution in a batch file called `getNames.bat`:

   ```
   #getNames.bat file
    C:\Python37\python.exe "C:\scripts\get_people.py"
   ```

   and VBA to call this .bat file:

```vb
    Sub GetNames()

       Dim wsh as Object
       Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
       Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
       Dim sScript As String

       Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       Set sScript = "C:\scripts\getNames.bat"
       wsh.Run sScript, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
       ... 
       'Rest is reading the content of the file that written by python script and send emails to someone.
       ...
    Exit Sub
```

However, the Python line does not run within VBA, but it runs if I manually execute from `cmd.exe`. In VBA the cmd screen pops up quickly and disappears.

2. Running Python scripts directly in VBA:

```vb
    Sub GetNames()

       Dim wsh as Object
       Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
       Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
       Dim sScript As String
       Dim PyExe As String
       Dim PyScript As String

       Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       Set PyExe = "C:\Python37\python.exe"
       Set PyScript = "C:\scripts\get_people.py"

       wsh.Run PyExe & " " & PyScript

       ....
       'This one crashes Outlook
       ...

       Exit Sub
```

I have tried PowerShell commands instead of Python in the .bat file:

```
 #getNames.bat file
      C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "Get-Date"
```

and this fails as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Shell "cmd /k C:\Python37\python.exe C:\scripts\get_people.py", vbmaximizedfocus 
End Sub
```

Comment: as soon as it hits the shell line cmd windows closes, unfortunately

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-constants

Comment: @DilshadAbduwali, Unless your Python program waits on user input, the expected behavior is that it runs and then immediately closes.  To see any output use `Shell "cmd /k C:\Python37\python.exe C:\scripts\get_people.py",vbmaximizedfocus`

Answer (score 0):

I created code very similar to your initial case and it worked for me. Try putting a 'pause' at the end of the batch file.

**trybat.bat**

```
@echo off
echo "hello world"
pause
```

**VBA code**

```
Sub Test()

  Dim wsh As Object
  Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
  Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

  Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  wsh.Run "C:\testdir\trybat.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
  MsgBox "ran"
End Sub
```

Comment: any standard cmd commands, like 'dir', works fine, but when I embed python.exe that runs a script is failing as soon as it hits the python line.

Comment: Does the _batch_ file work with the python.exe call?

Comment: batch script works fine with python call. not when called within VBA